# Multiline Text Processing : Editing sshd_config

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, sshd

I have multiple blocks at the end of my sshd_config files like theses:

```
Match User FOO
    ChrootDirectory /srv/www/FOO
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

How could I achieve the deletion of this block (and not other regarding FOO1, FOO2, etc.) in a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your `Match` blocks are at the end of the `sshd_config` file.
If your blocks are separated by empty lines, e.g.:

```
Match User FOO1
    PasswordAuthentication no

Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match User FOO
    ChrootDirectory /srv/www/FOO
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

then just delete from the line `Match User FOO` up to (and including) the first empty line:

```
sed '/^Match User FOO$/,/^$/d' sshd_config
```

If they're not separated, e.g.:

```
Match User BAZ
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match User FOO
    ChrootDirectory /srv/www/FOO
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
Match User FOO1
    PasswordAuthentication no
Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

then delete from `Match User FOO` up to (but not including) the first line that starts with `Match`:

```
sed '/^Match User FOO$/,/^Match.*/{//!d;/^Match User FOO$/d;}' sshd_config
```

Note you'll have to use `sed -i ...` to edit the file in-place. Check your `sed` manual for details/backup options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script using send and awk tools:

```
matchedLine=$(awk '/Match User FOO1/{ print NR; exit }' $1) 


if [ "$matchedLine" = "" ];then
echo "Match not found"
exit 1;
fi

sed -e "$matchedLine,$(awk "BEGIN {print $matchedLine + 5 }";)d;" $1
```

This script takes the filename of the ssh config file as its first argument. It then searches the file for the first occurrence of the match string (in this case 'Match User FOO1'). If it finds the match it will save its line number to the variable $matchedLine. Lastly using sed it will delete the line of the matched text and the following 5 lines. This script will not edit your actual file, it will only show you the content of the file with the matched lines removed. This way you can check if the script is working without any risk. If you want to edit the actual file just redirect the sed command to your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^Match User FOO$/,/^  *F.*-sftp$/c\ 
    The whole of the above line range is \
    replaced with this one block of text.\
    Use an empty "c"hange command or a   \
    "d"elete command to replace it with  \
    nothing at all.' <infile >outfile
```

It looks like you can rely on indents, by the way. So probably you can do:

```
sed '$!N;/^Match User FOO\n/,/\n[[:upper:]]/!P;D
'    <infile >outfile
```

Which will start deleting current lines while watching the next input line when the *Match* block is encountered, and stop deleting when the next input line begins with an upper-case letter.

The above command might need better explanation. It is the easiest and most robust method of doing this of which I am aware.

The workflow is like this:

1. For every input line which is `!`not the `$`last, also append the `N`ext input line  to pattern space.

   - While `sed` is typically known only to work a single line at a time this is merely its default behavior - `sed`'s editing *stream* is as customizable as you might wish it to be.
   - In this case the `N`ext command introduces a one-line *look-ahead* which is sustained - with the help of two other commands - throughout the course of the script.
2. Then check if the current context falls within that defined by the `/2/,/address/` *range* of lines specified.

   - `/^Match User FOO\n/` - The range *starts* when the matched pattern has already been in pattern-space for an entire cycle and would otherwise be `P`rinted to standard out. This is signified by the head-of-pattern-space `^`*anchor* and the trailing `\n`ewline in the pattern. This pattern represents an entire input line - from head to tail - but only *half* pattern-space at any one time.
   - `/\n[[:upper:]]/` - This is mostly a suggestion based on my reading of both your example's apparent indent-style and of [man sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) which would indicate that *all* relevant command primitives begin with an upper-case letter.
   - That, combined with the leading `\n`ewline escape in the pattern instruct `sed` only to end the range's match context when a line pulled in with `N`ext begins with one - and *not* with any white-space.
3. If it does `!`not fall within that range then `P`rint up to the first `\n`ewline character in pattern space to standard output, but if it does, print nothing at all for the current cycle.
4. Last, `D`elete up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space and end the current cycle.

   - This is very important - `D`elete does *not* pull in a new input line when the next cycle begins *unless* there are 0 `\n`ewlines in the current pattern space.
   - When there *is* a `\n`ewline in pattern space, `D`elete clears only up to and including it before recursing into a new cycle with what remains. What it `D`eletes, in fact, is exactly only as much as `P`rint will write to standard output in a context which does not match your range.

Now all of that is a very technical way of saying what I said before - from the start of your matched range until its indentation level ends and a new command beginning with an upper-case letter is found at the head of a line nothing is printed, while everything else is printed. And so your block is deleted from output in a very simple way which is indent-dependent and which enables you to control its selection merely by indenting your *Match* blocks as you already do.

Now, to fully understand all of that, you have to understand `sed`'s cycle, but it is also quite easily understood given an introspective `l`ook at how it works:

```
seq 10 | sed '$!N;/^4\n/,/\n9/!P;l;D'
```

The above command prints for two different reasons - the first *(when it applies)* is the `!P` range match context - which is what would go to stdout as suggested above.

The second is our `l`ook into how `sed` works - I tell it to print for *every* cycle an unequivocal representation of the current contents of pattern space. The results are these:

```
1             #This is Printed before we look at pattern space.
1\n2$         #This is our look - though only the 1st line is printed,
2             #each time one is, pattern space is actually 2 lines
2\n3$         #all of the time - it's our window into future output.
3
3\n4$         #3 prints, though 4 is in pattern space. But when pattern
4\n5$         #space matches ^4\n as it does now, nothing prints.
5\n6$
6\n7$         #And continues not to print...
7\n8$
8\n9$         #until the range ends here - when \n9 matches our future -
9             #now our current pattern space.
9\n10$        
10
10$
```

This makes controlling ranges - which some can find unintuitive because they require special contexts for start and end and extra matches for controlling those - much easier overall because you can start a range in the current context, and end it in a future one.

In other words, rather than saying...

> `/this_line/,/that_line/command` - *Apply command beginning from  **this_line** up to and including **that_line***

...you can phrase it a little more intuitively like...

> `N;/this_line\n/,/\nthat_line/command;D` - *Apply command beginning from **this_line** until **that_line***.

It is as robust as you could like - as there is no means of putting a `\n`ewline into a `sed` pattern space except as a result of an edit command *(such as `N`ext)* - and among the most performant solutions you might hope for.

So I'll borrow don's example data:

```
sed '$!N;/^Match User FOO\n/,/\n[[:upper:]]/!P;D' <<\IN
Match User BAZ
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match User FOO
    ChrootDirectory /srv/www/FOO
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
Match User FOO1
    PasswordAuthentication no
Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes
IN
```

...and...

```
sed '$!N;/^Match User FOO\n/,/\n[[:upper:]]/!P;D' <<\IN
Match User FOO1
    PasswordAuthentication no

Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match User FOO
    ChrootDirectory /srv/www/FOO
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes

IN
```

...will print...

```
Match User BAZ
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match User FOO1
    PasswordAuthentication no
Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

...and...

```
Match User FOO1
    PasswordAuthentication no

Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match User FOO2
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

...respectively.

It doesn't quit the range context on a blank line, though - all blank-lines following the block are regarded as a part of the block as written. So the blanks between the output lines in the second example are the ones which preceded it. It could, like:

```
sed '$!N;/^Match User FOO\n/,/\n\([[:upper:]].*\)*$/!P;D' <infile >oufile
```

...which would break the range context and begin writing to output again for either a blank line one begun with an upper-case case character. It could be made more general still:

```
sed '$!N;/^Match User FOO\n/,/\n\([^[:blank:]].*\)*$/!P;D' <infile >oufile
```

...which would break the range for any blank line or one opened with any non-blank character. In all cases though the breaking pattern is one on which you wish out to begin again, rather than a pattern for the last in a series for which you wish it to remain stopped.

Comment: This answer really shouldn't be downvoted - it's a damn shame. There are plenty of my answers which deserve it better - but this is a good answer.  It definitely answers the question - and it demonstrates how. Bummer.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using `sed` by using the `N` command:

```
sed -ri 'N;N;N;N;N;/^.+FOO\n.+/d' input.txt
```

What `N` command does is that it reads/appends the next line into your pattern space, hence making multi-line regex possible using `sed`.

For more, see [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-multi-line-file-operation-with-6-practical-examples/) tutorial.

Comment: Could someone give a reason as to why they voted it negative when this `sed` works perfectly fine?

Comment: Because this doesn't work for all kinds of reasons. In the first place, feed it the input file `\nFOO\n\n\n\n`. Next try removing a line or two from that. *Next* try it with a `sed` that behaves according to the `sed` POSIX spec where the `N`ext command and the last line are concerned. But you probably won't even get that one to run the script at all because you rather needlessly specify `-r` when the same script in a BRE is `N;N;N;N;N;/..*FOO\n./d`.

Answer (score -1):

While [sed is a possibility here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207880), it's easier to make this robust in awk. The following script skips lines starting at `Match User FOO` (or any variation in case and whitespace) and stops skipping at any other `Match User` line, and prints all non-skipped lines.

```
awk '
    tolower($1)=="match" && tolower($2) == "user" {skip = $3 == "foo"}
    !skip
'
```

In case your script is interrupted, make sure to write the output to a temporary file, then move that into place. Note that this could still result in data loss if someone else modifies the file at the same time.

```
awk … </etc/sshd_config >/etc/sshd_config.tmp &&
mv /etc/sshd_config.tmp /etc/sshd_config
```